# Adding this project as a reference circular dependency c# - when showing a win form

Tags: c#

I've got a problem - project MP_WIN depends on project DLV_WIN!

But now in the project DLV_WIN in one of it's forms i should show a form `frmContractPrint`  that's located in MP_WIN

```
using (frmContractPrint _frm = new frmContractPrint(wrapper))
      {
        _frm.ShowDialog();
      }
```

so you understanding that adding in DLV_WIN reference to MP_WIN would cause circular dependency.
The Problem is that the project is so huge that there is absolutely no way to somehow amend the architecture.

can you suggest the  fastest way I could resolve this issue and call that form!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a serious design flaw in your code. Projects should not have a tight binding both sides. If there is, you should combine the two projects.

Some options:

- Create an intermediate project where you put that form (and probably shared other stuff). Include that new project into both existing projects.
- Create a utility class that instantiates the `frmContractPrint` form in the upper project, while the lower depends on the method signature or an interface to interact with.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you provide an example for your second suggestion because as a junior developer i don't understand what you mean!